# RegEx how to block mix of number and letters in string

Tags: regex

I have a string for example:

1a2s3d4f5g6h7j8k9l0 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of fsdfsdf8s7d the printing and typesetting  fsdfsdf8s7d

And I want to find the "words" with the number and letters like:

`1a2s3d4f5g6h7j8k9l0` Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of `fsdfsdf8s7d` the printing and typesetting  `fsdfsdf8s7d`

I tried some code that I found here but nothing work well
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[a-zA-Z])\w+`

Meaning:

1. Match a position where there is a word with at least one digit in it.
2. Match a position where there is a word with at least one letter in it.
3. Match a word after that position.

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/KIo6lt/2)

Comment: This will also match pure numbers.